# Can't get pluralization to work in vue-i18n

Tags: vue-i18n

my message:

```
'time': '0 time | 1 time | {count} times'
```

my template:

```
{{ $t('time', repeat, { count: repeat }) }}
```

the ouput for `repeat` = 100:

```
0 time | 1 time | 100 times
```

instead of:

```
100 times
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for pluralization you are supposed to used `$tc` instead of `$t` (http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#tc):

```
{{ $tc('time', repeat, { count: repeat }) }}
```